# python-how to make an object 'suicide'?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

When I created an object in tkinter, how I can make the object destroy itself by embedded command in that object?
the code is like this; I'm coding a game that collects coins
I want to make coins disappear after collecting them.

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import random
import math
color=['gray','skyblue','orange','green','yellow','blue']
score=[0,0,0,0,0,0]
class Player:
    //player class. with wasd keys
class Coin:
    def __init__(self,canvas,player,i):
        self.Color=color[i]
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.player=player
            self.id=canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,20,15,fill=self.Color,state='normal',width=0)
        self.canvas_width=self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas_height=self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.x=random.randint(0,self.canvas_width-50)
        self.y=random.randint(0,self.canvas_height-50)
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y)
        self.i=i
        self.GetC=False

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id,self.x,self.y)
        pos=self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1]<=0:
            lv=random.randint(1,3)
            self.y=lv*self.i
        if pos[3]>=self.canvas_height:
            lv=random.randint(-3,-1)
            self.y=lv*self.i
        if pos[0]<=0:
            lh=random.randint(1,3)
            self.x=lh*self.i
        if pos[2]>=self.canvas_width:
            lh=random.randint(-3,-1)
            self.x=lh*self.i
        if self.hit_player(pos)==True:
            self.GetC=True

    def hit_player(self,pos):
        player_pos=self.canvas.coords(self.player.id)
        if pos[2]>=player_pos[0] and pos[0] <=player_pos[2]:
            if pos[3]>=player_pos[1] and pos[1]<= player_pos[3]:
                return True
        return False

    def scoring(self):
        if self.GetC==True:
            score[0]=round(score[0]+0.01*pow(2,self.i),2)
            score[self.i]=round(score[self.i]+0.01,2)
            self.GetC=False
tk=Tk()
tk.title("GAME")
tk.resizable(0,0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)

canvas=Canvas(tk,width=500,height=400,bd=0,highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

player=Player(canvas,'blue')
coin=[]
for k in range(50):
    l=6-int(math.log2(random.randint(2,32)))
    coin.append(Coin(canvas,player,l))
inv=canvas.create_text(250,200,text=score,state='hidden')
while 1:
    if player.Toggle==True:
        canvas.itemconfig(inv,state='normal')
    if player.Toggle==False:
        canvas.itemconfig(inv,state='hidden')
    for k in range(50):
        coin[k].scoring()
        coin[k].draw()
    canvas.itemconfig(inv,text=score)
    if player.Q==True:
        break
    player.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: If the coins are drawn on the canvas, you should check for `canvas.delete` method. I also advise you to use `tk.after` instead of `time.sleep` because the latter makes the window unresponsive during the sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example where the coins disappear when the player click on them:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from random import random

root = Tk()
can = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400, bg="white")
can.pack()

def collect(id):
    can.delete(id)

for i in range(10):
    x = random()*380
    y = random()*380
    id=can.create_oval(x, y, x+20, y+20, fill="yellow")
    can.tag_bind(id, "<Button-1>", lambda event, j=id: collect(j))

root.mainloop()
```